# Elastic Beanstalk CLI using multiple acc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

In ~/.aws/config I have

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = abcd
aws_secret_access_key = abcd

[profile eb-cli2]
aws_access_key_id = abcda
aws_secret_access_key = abcda
```

how I can switch between this profiles ?

for example how I can run `eb list` for `[profile eb-cli2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first off need to be in an elastic beanstalk directory, e.g. one that has been initialised for use with `eb`.

In your `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` you need to update the profile:

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: dev
global:
  application_name: api
  default_platform: Node.js
  default_region: eu-west-1
  profile: eb-cli2
  sc: git
```

The key line is the `profile: eb-cli2`

This does not work:

```
eb list --profile eb-cli2
```

Comment: every time ? make changes in configuration file ? maybe is shortest way ?

Comment: yeah, annoying, I always end up provisioning stuff on the wrong profile first. Terminating and then redeploying with the correct profile. I assume the `--profile` works for `create`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `~/.aws/config`, use `~/.aws/credentials` file for configuring credentials

```
[eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = abcd
aws_secret_access_key = abcd

[eb-cli2]
aws_access_key_id = abcda
aws_secret_access_key = abcda
```

Then use: `eb list --profile eb-cli2`

Comment: Now as I see i have only `~/.aws/config` I will rename it to `~/.aws/credentials` that's enought ?

Comment: No, create a new file since your `~/.aws/config` may have configuration other than creds.  See the format `[eb-cli2]`.